# Select records from one table that are referenced by a column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table structure in my SQL Server Database:

| ID | NAME | VERSION | VERSION_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | A | NULL |
| 2 | Test1 | B | 1 |
| 3 | Test1 | C | 2 |
| 4 | Test2 | A | NULL |

Records, e.g. representing  documents and their versions A, B, C and so on.
Version C refers to its predecessor version B in the VERSION_ID field.
And version B refers to its predecessor version A in the VERSION_ID field.

The question is:
Is it possible to use a single SELECT query to get all previous versions that belong to the current version?

I would like to see the following in the result of the SELECT query when I query all versions for record "Test1 Version C":

| ID | NAME | VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | A |
| 2 | Test1 | B |

Any help is much appreciated.
I hope the title is not misleading but I didn't find better words to describe my question.

Comment: Is the last table your expect result? Can you explain more?

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi yes, it is my expected result. I want to find all previous versions for record with ID "3". Version C is the latest version of "Test1" and I want to find version A and B. How could the select look like that returns my expected result? SELECT ... FROM table1 WHERE ID=3

Comment: Is it expected to have tree-like versioning? B -> C, C->B, D->B (where -> denotes parenting). And if yes are only B and A still expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using the `recursive cte` since you have rows connected recursively :

```
with cte(ID, NAME, VERSION, VERSION_ID) as (
  select ID, NAME, VERSION, VERSION_ID
  from mytable 
  where NAME = 'Test1' and VERSION = 'C'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.ID, t.NAME, t.VERSION, t.VERSION_ID
  FROM mytable t
  inner join cte c on c.VERSION_ID = t.ID
)
select ID, NAME, VERSION
from cte
where VERSION <> 'C'
order by ID;
```

Result :

```
ID  NAME    VERSION
1   Test1   A
2   Test1   B
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RRbt5BxS)

Answer (score 1):

Us simple `EXISTS` here:

```sql
SELECT ID,  NAME,   VERSION
FROM my_table t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM my_table t2
  WHERE t2.VERSION_ID = t1.ID
)
```

It does what it says: checks if for current row exists row with `VERSION_ID` containing current `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Just join back to the same table.

```
SELECT T1.[ID], T1.[NAME], T1.[VERSION] 
FROM MYTABLE As T1
INNER JOIN MYTABLE AS T2 ON T1.[ID] = T2.[VERSION_ID]
```